# Posting a Postman Response Values to Flock using Collection Variables

Tags: postman, webhooks, azure-devops-rest-api, postman-collection-runner

I am setting up a proof of concept to monitor the status of some Azure DevOps build agents by executing the below Azure DevOps API command in Postman.

[image: Azure DevOps API Agent Listing]

I'm then extracting the `Name` and `Hosted` status of each agent using the below Postman commands, with the resultant output then getting set as Postman Collection variables, as depicted in the image further below.

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json().value
jsonData.forEach((item, index) => { 
   pm.collectionVariables.set(item["name"], item["isHosted"])      
})
```

[image: Postman Collection Variables]

Finally, what I then seek to do is POST the entire set of Collection variables to an instant messaging service such as Flock (or even Slack), using a custom webhook in Postman. I have successfully managed to set up this custom webhook using another Postman API command which is depicted below.

[image]

However, as also shown above, I'm only ever able to successfully POST the agent status to Flock one at a time, by commenting out all but one agent reference. I need to be able to:

1. Send the entire set of Agent status value to Flock in one go.
2. Not be required to explicitly enter the name of each Collection variable to obtain its corresponding value.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can consider adding the **postman.setNextRequest()** to your foreach script to send requests multiple times in one run.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create Get Pools request and Post Flock request in the Postman collection.

Step2: Add the following script sample in the Get Pools request:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json().value
jsonData.forEach((item, index) => { 
   console.log(item["name"]);
   pm.collectionVariables.set("name", item["name"]);
   pm.collectionVariables.set(item["name"], item["isHosted"]);
   postman.setNextRequest('Post Flock');
})
```

This step will set two variables: the pool name based on the agent pool name and set the expected pool name and ishosted value.

Step3: Use the variable in the Post Flock request.

For example:

```
{
  "text": "Agent Status - {{{{name}}}}"
}
```

{{name}} represent the agent Pool name. {{{{name}}}} represent the ishosted value of hte Agent Pool.

Step4: You can use the **Collection Runner** to run the script.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Customize request order in a collection run](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/running-collections/building-workflows/)

> The postman.setNextRequest() is intended for use when running a collection using the Collection Runner, the Postman CLI, or Newman. It has no effect when you run a request using Send.

Comment: Much appreciated Kevin. Will definitely give that a go and provide some feedback. However, just for my clarity, where you stated ".............{{name}} represent the agent Pool name. {{{{name}}}} represent the ishosted value of hte Agent Pool." did you actually mean {{{{isHosted}}}} rather than {{{{name}}}} ?

Comment: @hitman126 For example: **PoolName: true/false** {{name}} = PoolName and  {{{{name}}}} = true/false.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm afraid I just can't get the proposed solution working. Yes, the iterated/looped values are getting displayed in the Postman console, but the same iterated or looped values are not getting sent to my messaging client (Flock) via the Postman POST request.